# Typescript doesn't catch a bad type on setState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

During setState, Typescript allows to pass any value and doesn't catch an error.

```
export enum InfoType {
  STREET_NAME = 'street',
  ADDITIONAL_STREET = 'additionalStreet',
  POSTAL_CODE = 'postCode',
  CITY = 'city',
}

export type AddressInfo<T> = {
  [K in InfoType]: T;
};
```

My state is defined as

```
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState<AddressInfo<boolean>>({
    street: false,
    additionalStreet: false,
    postCode: false,
    city: false,
  });
```

But during set state I can pass a string as value

```
//this doesn't throw an error
const onFocusHandler = (infoType: InfoType) => {
 setFormErrors((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [infoType]: 'foo'  }));
};
```

infoType is arg passed to function from onFocus callback

```
onFocus={() => onFocusHandler(InfoType.POSTAL_CODE)}
```

I want 'foo' to throw an error and to accept only boolean. AddressInfo type is being used on another state too that is pretty much the same, but should accepts strings only as value.

I use computed property because I have many different inputs and I want to use one onFocusHandler for all of them. I pass the key of enum to onFocusHandler and change the state value of that key

I tried to use combinations of keyof and typeofs, but as I am not very pro-efficient with Typescript, I couldn't make it work

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear. Typescript is doing exactly as you instructed it. For example, setFormErrors must be from a useState tuple, the tuple you are not showing us here.

Comment: @KelvinUkuejubolaOritsetimeyi Sorry, I edited the question. setFormErrors() doesn't throw an error if I pass string as a value

Comment: what is `infoType`?

Comment: value of enum passed as arg to the function. Edited

Comment: Can you show more of your code? The types look fine so the problem is likely elsewhere. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwJKIGYQCoCeYwcA3gFBxwDKeASgKIN4D6AcgIICyDcAvHADkAZxhRgwGIIA0lOBwAiCjHgwB5TgBkWtRs35CAhgBNjASxhmIiQwBtqYiVNlUACmtodtAYTULeAoKQot4QxsAyct4qAJoGggDGFgSRAL7k5KCQsHAwRCQcpuLCwli4ADx4AHwGFFQA2gDScGaImDj4+QC6AFxweADc5KlD5NjIiAmW1nAAYgAUYIYEthAmfYXGxaUd5QBGEBC2wIaIVQCUZOTiMMhQbUsra8ZD6eQJ1qJwJlvAJWUQDZFP47CoHI4nM61ORUUTiSR9bB2YTAFxUb6mCxWGz2RwIuBI2wotFUYIwULhRHI1EwuBJPJUok09IfRBfVq4QjEPoArkkAS8-IAOmieBiowWpDgQplP22AOkcHqHM6xF6QlwEEEcFS5yAA

Comment: @HunterMcMillen There is nothing more to it. onFocus that is on RN TextInput component call onFocusHandler() (with 'postCode' essentially). By using computed property, it changes the value of state postCode to false (it is false initially but doesn't matter here). I noticed that if I get rid the computed property [infoType] from setFormErrors() and use something clearly defined in the state - as street key, it does throw me an error. So <..>({ ...prevState, street: 'foo'  }) does throw an error, but [infoType]: 'foo' doesn't. Is it possible due to setState not aware of something ?

Comment: This seems similar https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26635 but was for setState w/ Class components

Answer (score 0):

An error won't be thrown because Typescript doesn't catch runtime errors. It catches them at compile time. Looking at the code, everything is fine at compile time until you run it. Just one of the limitations of Typescript, so welcome!!!